# Add whole emoji list from dictionnary to a string array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift3, nsdictionary

I have a function which add classical emoji to a string

```
var emojiList: [String] = []

func initEmoji() {
    for c in 0x1F601...0x1F64F{
        self.emojiList.append(String(describing: UnicodeScalar(c)!))
    }
}
```

I would like to use other pod with Emoji, like [Emoji-Swift](https://github.com/safx/Emoji-Swift) or [SwiftEmoji](https://github.com/nerdyc/SwiftEmoji)

I don't know how to append my emojiList array with all those new Emoji.

Could someone kindly tell me how to do ?

It might be easy, but I'm stuck ..

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution (swift 3)!

```
var emojiDictionary = String.emojiDictionary
   for (myKey,myValue) in emojiDictionary {
    self.emojiList.append(myValue)
```